# Number Theory Problem - finding a solution-forming function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 4 q$$

What are all possible $f(k)$ and $g(k)$ such that for all positive integers $k$, $n=f(k)$ and $q=g(k)$ are integer solutions to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n(n+1)=8q$. Thus, $8\mid n(n+1) \to 8\mid n$ or $8\mid n+1$ because $8=2^3$ and $\text{gdc}(n,n+1)=1$ for all $n$.

**Case 1:** $n=8k$

Then $8k(8k+1)=8q\to q=k(8k+1)$

**Case 2:** $n=8k-1$

Then $(8k-1)(8k-1+1)=8q\to q=(8k-1)k$

Finally, for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(n,q)=(8k,k(8k+1))$ and $(n,q)=(8k-1,(8k-1)k)$ are the solutions.